# VBA not recognizing Sheet activate

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I am trying to use solver in VBA. My inputs are in a different sheet than the macro button (I cannot change that) and for some reason Excel 2007 recognizes Sheets("Core").Activate, whereas the excel 365 does not. What am I doing wrong, as in excel 365, it just ignores the first line of the code?

```
Sheets("Core").Activate
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AO$10", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
SolverOk SetCell:="$AZ$8", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$AO$10", Engine _
    :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve (True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass actual ranges as parameters, instead of selecting a worksheet and passing range addresses:

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Core")

    SolverAdd CellRef:=.Range("AO10"), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    
    SolverOk SetCell:=.Range("AZ8"), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, _
             ByChange:=.Range("AO10"), Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
End With
 
SolverSolve True
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but it still ignores it for some reason